# SwiftUI - Sort a display a JSON file in SwiftUI with sections, either in sections or sorted

Tags: ios, list, sorting, swiftui

I have a JSON file with the following content:

```
[
{
   "id":"s1",
   "group":"Fruits",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Apple"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Pineapple"
      },
   ]
},
{
   "id":"s2",
   "group":"Vegetables",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "name":"Carots"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "name":"Cucumber"
      }
   ]
},
]
```

I would like to give the user 2 choices:

- display them in their groups with sections
- display all vegetables and fruits sorted

Here are the two code snippets and the results:

```
// sorted in sections
List {
        ForEach(itemData) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.group)) {
                ForEach(section.items) { item in
                    ItemRow(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Result sorted in sections as expected:

Fruits

- Apple
- Pineapple

Vegetables

- Carots
- Cucumber

  ```
  // items without sections
  List {
      ForEach(itemData) { section in
          ForEach(section.items) { item in
              ItemRow(item: item)
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Result as expected unsorted:

- Apple
- Pineapple
- Carots
- Cucumber

How do I sort and display the second option by "name"?

Answer (score 0):

try this:  (i do not know how you called your variable, so i called it "name". Replace it with the name of your variable)

```
List {
            ForEach(itemData.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.group)) {
                    ForEach(section.items.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { item in
                        ItemRow(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```